# How to connect one android activity to other?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to do something like, when I click on "Button_Set" Button on **Activity 1**, it should set the **Edit Box** of **Activity 2**.
I know the below code gives the Null pointer exception and is expected to not work.

Any Idea how do I do this?

```
order.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class));
                setorder.setText("Welcome User");

           }
  });
```

Comment: @pappbence96 i don't think this is duplicate question. He just want to transfer user to new activity and set text to edittext or textview. Welcome String.

Comment: If he wants to pass the welcoming string from the first activity, then it's a duplicate. If he doesn't, it's a little convoluted attempt to a simple problem (baking the text into the XML)

Comment: @pappbence96, No. Thank you, that solved my query. Possibly I couldn't get the exact keywords for searching the above answer..

Comment: If the linked duplicate solved your issue, please select the "That solved my problem!" option, so this question will be marked as such.

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class));
           }
      });
```